# integration by parts with infinite limit

Tags: calculus, integration

Can someone help me figure out how this equation:

$$
\int_{w}^{\infty} (W(x) - W(w)) \ dF(x)
$$

becomes

$$
\int_{w}^{\infty} W'(x)(1 - F(x)) \ dx
$$

It is supposed to be done by the help of integration by parts. Using this method I get close, but not quite correct.

This is my best attempt:

Integration by parts formula:
$$
\int f(x)g'(x) \, dx = f(x)g(x) - \int f'(x)g(x) \, dx
$$

In my case i define:
$$
f(x) = (W(x) - W(w), \quad g'(x) = f(x), \quad f'(x) = W'(x), \quad g(x) = F(x)
$$

Plugging this into the formula I get:

$$
\int_{w}^{\infty} [(W(x) - W(w))f(x)] \, dx = (W(x) - W(w))F(x) - \int_{w}^{\infty} (W'(x)F(x)) \, dx
$$
So the left side corresponds with my originial destination, but the first term of the right side would have to equal
$$
\int_{w}^{\infty} (W'(x)) \, dx
$$

For the right side to equal the equation I am supposed to end up with.

Info: F(x) is the CDF of x, and f(x) is the PDF. So F(x) tends to 1 at the upper limit of infintiy. The distribution of x-values starts at some low value (can be lower than w).

Comment: What do you know about $W$ and $F$? If $F$ is a probability distribution function then you can just write $W(x) - W(w) = \int_w^x W'(t)\,dt$ then exchange the order of integration.

Comment: Where is your work? What is "close, but not quite correct"?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I am new here so I probably didn't right my question as clearly as I should have. I have updated my question with my attempt, plus information about F(x). I dont know what information about W(x) that is relevant, the equation is from an academic paper I am trying to grasp fully, so W(x) depends on a lot of different things. Maybe it is enough to say it is assumed to be differentiable?